# Array of objects - Merge objects by name and sum their counts

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stucked and need help. I have an object and need to merge objects by name and sum their counts.

```
products = {
    fruit: [
        { name: orange, count: 1 },
        { name: orange, count: 2 },
        { name: apple, count: 3 },
        { name: apple, count: 2 },
    ],
    vegetables: [
        { name: tomato, count: 3 },
        { name: tomato, count: 4 },
        { name: onion, count: 1 },
        { name: onion, count: 3 },
    ]
}
```

Final goal is to get object like this

```
products = {
    fruit: [
        { name: orange, count: 3 },
        { name: apple, count: 5 },
    ],
    vegetables: [
        { name: tomato, count: 7 },
        { name: onion, count: 4 },
    ]
}
```

Using for in loop I got into products object. I tried with reduce function but didn't succeed. Also I tried with [... new Set()] and I managed to merge objects by name, but counts didn't sum their values.

```
let temp = {}
for(let category in products){
    const product = products[category]
    temp = product.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        if(acc.name === curr.name){
            return{
                name: acc.name,
                count: acc.count + curr.count
            }
        }
    }, {})
}
```

Comment: Your `reduce` doesn’t return anything in case `acc.name === curr.name` is `false`. `acc.name` also doesn’t seem to make any sense. Please see [this Q&A](/q/19233283/4642212) and read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). `.reduce((acc, curr) => {`…`}, {})` means `acc` is your intermediate result (“acc” is short for “accumulator”; the intermediate result is also the initial `{}` at the start and the final result at the end; you want this to be a `{ name: count,`…`}` structure); `curr` is the current `{ name, count }` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grouping by hash approach:

```js
const products={fruit:[{name:'orange',count:1},{name:'orange',count:2},{name:'apple',count:3},{name:'apple',count:2}],vegetables:[{name:'tomato',count:3},{name:'tomato',count:4},{name:'onion',count:1},{name:'onion',count:3}]};

const result = Object.keys(products).reduce((prods, key) => {
    const items = products[key];
    const grouped = items.reduce((acc, { name, count }) => {
        acc[name] ??= { name, count: 0 };
        acc[name].count += count;
        return acc;
    }, {});
    prods[key] = Object.values(grouped);
    
    return prods;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note that this doesn’t add anything new to the [existing answers](/q/19233283/4642212). You’re not addressing the flaws in OP’s code.

Comment: @SebastianSimon So, why you don't flag this Q as a dublicate?

Comment: Because of lack of certainty. The OP does have code; the flaws in the code might need to be addressed by more specific duplicate targets than the general _“How to do this”_ Q&A.

Answer (score 1):

The below may be one possible implementation to obtain the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// helper method to manipulate 
// the fruit, vegetables arrays
const arrReduce = arr => (
  Object.entries(         // extract key-value pairs from below ".reduce()" result
    arr.reduce(           // iterate over the array with "acc" as accumulator
      (acc, {name, count}) => ({
        ...acc,           // retain existing "acc" entries
        [name]: (acc?.[name] ?? 0) + count
      }),                 // accumulate the "count" as-per "name"
      {}                  // initial "acc" is an empty-object 
    )
  ).map(
    ([k, v]) => ({        // transform the key-value pairs into objects
      name: k, count: v   // "name" and "count" props with corresponding values
    })
  )
);

// the method that does the transformation
const groupAndSum = obj => (
  Object.fromEntries(     // re-construct object from below result
    Object.entries(obj)   // transform key-value pairs into [k, v] array
    .map(                 // iterate over the array created
      ([k, v]) => ([      // use the "arrReduce()" helper method on the value-array
        k, arrReduce(v)
      ])
    )
  )
);


const products = {
  fruit: [{
    name: 'orange',
    count: 1
  }, {
    name: 'orange',
    count: 2
  }, {
    name: 'apple',
    count: 3
  }, {
    name: 'apple',
    count: 2
  }],
  vegetables: [{
    name: 'tomato',
    count: 3
  }, {
    name: 'tomato',
    count: 4
  }, {
    name: 'onion',
    count: 1
  }, {
    name: 'onion',
    count: 3
  }]
};


console.log(groupAndSum(products));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments describe the various steps

**References**

This solution employs the following JavaScript features

1. Object.fromEntries()
2. Object.entries()
3. Array.map()
4. Arrow functions
5. Array.reduce()
6. De-structuring
7. `...` spread operator (to effect a shallow-copy)
8. `?.` optional chaining
9. `??` nullish coalescing operator

**EDIT**

As noted in comments by Sebastian Simon, this answer does not provide any feedback on OP's attempt. Consequently, this edit is added here. Thank you [Sebastian Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4642212/sebastian-simon) for your feedback. Appreciate it.

**Fixing OP's code**

```js
const products={fruit:[{name:'orange',count:1},{name:'orange',count:2},{name:'apple',count:3},{name:'apple',count:2}],vegetables:[{name:'tomato',count:3},{name:'tomato',count:4},{name:'onion',count:1},{name:'onion',count:3}]};

let temp = {}
for(let category in products){
    const product = products[category]
    temp = {
      ...temp,      // one needs to append results to "temp"
      [category]: Object.entries( // extract key-value pairs from result of ".reduce()"
        product
          .reduce(    // the ".reduce()" result needs to go within "category"
            (acc, curr) => {
            return {  // no need of "if" here. Always return an object
              ...acc, // retain existing "accumulator"
              [curr.name]: (    // add / update key "curr.name" of "acc" object
                acc
                ?.[curr.name]   // use existing "count" if "name" exists in "acc"
                ?? 0            // nullish coalescing to zero (if "name" not in "acc")
              ) + curr.count    // always add "curr.count" to the value
            };
          },
          {}
        )
      ).map(      // transform the key-value pair into the desired "name", "count" object
        ([k, v]) => ({
          name: k, count: v
        })
      )
    }
};

console.log(temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**Explanation**

The changes made along with description is added to the above code-snippet.

Comment: Note that this doesn’t really add anything new to the [existing answers](/q/19233283/4642212). You’re not addressing the flaws in OP’s code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array#map`, `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` methods as follows:

```js
const input = { fruit: [ { name: "orange", count: 1 }, { name: "orange", count: 2 }, { name: "apple", count: 3 }, { name: "apple", count: 2 } ], vegetables: [{ name: "tomato", count: 3 },{ name: "tomato", count: 4 },{ name: "onion", count: 1 }, { name: "onion", count: 3 }]};

const output =  Object.fromEntries( Object.entries(input)
    .map(([category, produce]) =>
        [
            category,
            Object.entries(
                produce.reduce((prev,{name,count}) =>
                    ({...prev,[name]:(prev[name] || 0) + count}), {}
                )
            )
            .map(([name, count]) => ({name,count}))
        ]
    )
);

console.log( output );
```

**YOUR CODE**

You could also edit your code as follows; you have first have to look in `acc` to see if a matching item (by name) exists - `Array#find`. If found, update the count, otherwise `push` `curr` into `acc`. **BE SURE TO RETURN `acc`!** The initial value should be an empty array, `[]`.

```js
const products = { fruit: [ { name: "orange", count: 1 }, { name: "orange", count: 2 }, { name: "apple", count: 3 }, { name: "apple", count: 2 } ], vegetables: [{ name: "tomato", count: 3 },{ name: "tomato", count: 4 },{ name: "onion", count: 1 }, { name: "onion", count: 3 }]};

const output = {}
for(let category in products) {
    const product = products[category]
    output[category] = product.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        let target = acc.find(item => item.name === curr.name);
        if( target ) {
            target.count += curr.count;
        } else {
            acc.push( curr );
        }
        return acc;
    }, [])
};

console.log( output );
```